# C# Visual Studio - why do I get an error "Not all code paths return a value"?

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;
using System;

namespace andyify
{
    internal class CommonOpenFileDialog
    {
        internal readonly string FileName;

        public string IntialDirectory { get; internal set; }
        public bool IsFolderPicker { get; internal set; }

        internal CommonFileDialogResult ShowDialog()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And I am getting this error:

> Error CS0161
> 'CommonOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()': not all code paths return a value.

Does anyone know why this is? Can someone please help me? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This method:

```
internal CommonFileDialogResult ShowDialog()
{
        
}
```

doesn't return anything. You must either return a `CommonFileDialogResult` or throw an exception, such as

```
internal CommonFileDialogResult ShowDialog()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException("Need to implement this.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving the following error [Compiler Error CS0161](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0161)

> not all code paths return a value
>
> **A method that returns a value must have a return statement in all code
> paths**. For more information, see [Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods).

---

Further more

[Methods (Return values)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods#return-values)

> Methods with a non-void return type **are required to use the return
> keyword to return a value**.

---

As noted by [Eric J.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141172/eric-j) and to add to the documentation (which does seem to be lacking),

> Methods with a non-void return type are required to use the return
> keyword to return a value or throw an exception

Your method has a return

```
internal CommonFileDialogResult ShowDialog()
{
        
}
```

Either set it to void,

```
internal void ShowDialog()
{
        
}
```

or return a value

```
internal CommonFileDialogResult ShowDialog()
{
    return null // just to get it to compile
}
```

If this is a required to be implemented by an interface, throw an exception

Comment: `A method that returns a value must have a return statement in all code paths` Not exactly. A given code path must either return a value or throw an exception.

Comment: @EricJ. Yeah, that is certainly a valid point and should definitely be added to the documentation for both the Exception code and the return value in the Methods page. Maybe you can make a git pull request?

Answer (score 1):

```
  internal CommonFileDialogResult ShowDialog()
    {
        
    }
```

CommonFileDialogResult indicates that you expect th method to return an object of type CommonFileDialogResul.
solutions:

1. throw new NotImplementedException("Need to implement this."); as shown by Eic J.
2. return null
3. return new CommonFileDialogResult()
4. change method signature from  CommonFileDialogResult to void.

Answer (score 0):

this is because your code expects a return value which isn't there in the last function